# How do I properly use a Callback in this code? (Kivy)

Tags: python, callback, kivy

Why does this code not work? I think it's something to do with x1 being already defined because I get the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x1' referenced before assignment" whenever I click b1. Please I've searched the entire Internet with no luck.... Sorry I'm relatively new to Python and programming.

```
import calendar
import datetime
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

now = datetime.datetime.now()
h = now.hour
m = now.minute
s = now.second
year = now.year
month = now.month
day = now.day
home = 'home.'
weekday1 = calendar.weekday(year, month, day)
if  len(str(m)) == 1:
  zero = '0'
else:
  zero = ''
if len(str(s)) == 1:
  zero1 = '0'
else:
  zero1 = ''

if weekday1 == 0:
  day = 'Monday'
  time = '''Period 1/2/3/4 = History
Period 5/6 = Japanese'''
  if h == 8 and m >= 40:
    current = 'Homeroom.'
  elif h == 9 or (h == 10 and m <= 40):
    current = 'History.'
  elif h == 10 and m > 40:
    current = 'recess.'
  elif h == 11 or (h == 12 and m <= 40):
    current = 'History.'
  elif (h == 12 and m > 40) or (h == 13 and m <= 20):
    current = 'lunch.'
  elif (h == 13 and m > 20) or h == 14:
    current = 'Japanese.'
  else:
    current = home
elif weekday1 == 1:
  day = 'Tuesday'
  time = '''Period 1 = English
Period 2 = Maths
Period 3/4 = English
Period 5/6 = ICT'''
  if h == 8 and m>= 40:
    current = 'Homeroom.'
  elif h == 9 and m <= 50:
    current = 'English.'
  elif (h == 9 and m > 50) or (h == 10 and m <= 40):
    current = 'Maths.'
  elif h == 10 and m > 40:
    current = 'recess.'
  elif h == 11 or (h == 12 and m <= 40):
    current = 'English.'
  elif (h == 12 and m > 40) or (h == 13 and m <= 20):
    current = 'lunch.'
  elif (h == 13 and m > 20) or h == 14:
    current = 'ICT.'
  else:
    current = home
elif weekday1 == 2:
  day = 'Wednesday'
  time = '''Period 1/2 = Science Extended
Period 3 = English
Period 4 = Maths
Period 5/6 = Science'''
  if h == 8 and m >= 40:
    current = 'Homeroom.'
  elif h == 9 or (h == 10 and m <= 40):
    current = 'Science Extended.'
  elif h == 10 and m > 40:
    current = 'recess.'
  elif h == 11 and m <= 50:
    current = 'English.'
  elif (h== 11 and m > 50) or (h == 12 and m <= 40):
    current = 'Maths.'
  elif (h == 12 and m > 40) or (h == 13 and m <= 20):
    current = 'lunch.'
  elif (h == 13 and m > 20) or h == 14:
    current = 'Science.'
  else:
    current = home
elif weekday1 == 3:
  day = 'Thursday'
  time = '''Period 1/2 = Art
Period 3 = Science
Period 4 = Wellbeing
Period 5 = English
Period 6 = Maths'''
  if h == 8 and m >= 40:
    current = 'Homeroom.'
  elif (h == 10 and m <= 40) or h == 9:
    current = 'Art.'
  elif h == 10 and m > 40:
    current = 'recess.'
  elif h == 11 and m <= 50:
    current = 'Science.'
  elif (h == 11 and m > 50) or (h == 12 and m <= 40):
    current = 'Wellbeing.'
  elif (h == 12 and m > 40) or (h == 13 and m < 20):
    current = 'lunch.'
  elif (h == 13 and m >= 20) or (h == 14 and m <= 10):
    current = 'English.'
  elif h == 14 and m > 10:
    current = 'Maths.'
  else:
    current = home
elif weekday1 == 4:
  day = 'Friday'
  time = '''Period 1/2 = PE
Period 3 = English
Period 4 = Maths
Period 5/6 = Music'''
  if h == 8 and m >= 40:
    current = 'Homeroom.'
  elif h == 9 or (h == 10 and m <= 40):
    current = 'PE.'
  elif h == 10 and m > 40:
    current = 'recess.'
  elif h == 11 and m <= 50:
    current = 'English.'
  elif (h == 11 and m > 50) or (h == 12 and m <= 40):
    current = 'Maths.'
  elif (h == 12 and m > 40) or (h == 13 and m < 20):
    current = 'lunch.'
  elif (h == 13 and m >= 20) or h == 14:
    current = 'Music.'
  else:
    current = home
else:
  day = 'a weekend'
  time = 'You have none.'
if day == 'a weekend':
  a = "You don't have to be anywhere."
else:
  a = ('You should be at ' + current)

a1 = ('Today is ' + day + '.')
a2 = ('''Today your timetable is:
''' + time)
a3 = ('The current time is ' + str(h) + ':' + zero + str(m) + ':' + zero1 + str(s) + '.')

t1 = 'What is the day today?'
t2 = 'What is the current time?'
t3 = 'What is my timetable today?'
t4 = 'Where should I be?'

x1, x2, x3, x4 = '', '', '', ''

def callback1(object):
  del x1
  x1 = a1
def callback2(object):
  x2 = a3
def callback3(object):
  x3 = a2
def callback4(object):
  x4 = a

b1 = Button(text = t1)
b1.bind(on_press = callback1)

layout = GridLayout(cols = 2)
layout.add_widget(b1)
layout.add_widget(Label(text = x1))
layout.add_widget(Button(text = t2))
layout.add_widget(Label(text = x2))
layout.add_widget(Button(text = t3))
layout.add_widget(Label(text = x3))
layout.add_widget(Button(text = t4))
layout.add_widget(Label(text = x4))

class TimeTable(App):
  def build(self):
    return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
  TimeTable().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because you try to delete a global variable (`x1`) in a local context (`callback1`), without declaring it as global before.

You could do:

```
global x1
del x1
```

But there is a more general issue with what you are trying to accomplish, when you say `text = x1`, it just passes the current value of `x1` to the `text` property of the `Label` you create, and changing the value of `x1` later has no effect on this, what you want is to change widget.text to the new value (and you should rename `object` to `widget` in these callbacks, `object` is the name of the base class in python, so you shouldn't use it as a parameter or anything).

Also, the way you structure your code won't work well in the long term, you should do more things in methods of your class (most of what you do before could be done in `build`).